# Blink and change the title of website when user isn't in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grab user attencion back to the website when hes in different tab, so i would like to recreate effect from sephora.pl

If you tab out you see an nice alert as title ('What are you waiting for?'), and then back to page title. Effect stops when you are on the page again. I managed to create this parts and i stuck. Any idea how to make it blink?

```
$(function() {
    // Get page title
    var pageTitle = $("head title").text();

    // Change page title on blur
    $(window).blur(function() {
      $("title").text("Come back to us");
        // Somehow make it blink between Come back to us and pageTitle every 1200ms or so...
    });

    // Change page title back on focus
    $(window).focus(function() {
      $("title").text(pageTitle);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `setInterval`?

Comment: Probably yes, but im not sure if it can be just easily broken when user is back in tab and how to make it works with my current state

Comment: That sounds like a really annoying and invasive user experience. Are you sure that is a good idea? I'd immediately close your tab and never come back, for sure.

Comment: @Yarushi: *"im not sure if it can be just easily broken when user is back in tab"* - `clearInterval`.  Give it a try, see how it goes.  If you encounter a specific technical problem with your implementation, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.

Comment: Huge ecommerce is using it, so i suppose it draws the conversion rate a bit higher https://www.sephora.pl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after small-talks in commentary section i managed to make it work like this:

```
const orginalTitle = $(document).prop('title');
function flashText() {
  const newTitle = ('Back to us!');
  if ($(document).prop('title') === orginalTitle) {
    document.title = newTitle;
  } else {
     document.title = orginalTitle;
  }
}

$(function changeTitle() {
    let nIntervId;
    $(window).blur(function() {
    if (!nIntervId) {
    nIntervId = setInterval(flashText, 1100);
    }
    });
    $(window).focus(function() {
      clearInterval(nIntervId);
      nIntervId = null; 
      $("title").text(orginalTitle);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain javascript. Something like this;

```
let defaultTitle = document.title
window.onblur = () => {
   //change title, blink title, whatever
   document.title = "New title"
}
window.onfocus = () => {
   //back to default title
   document.title = defaultTitle
}
```

BTW, yeh, I've seen it on Alibaba, so guess it do increase leads.